# it seems that i only have one key in my localstorage and it keeps storing all the values into it(localstorage)

Tags: javascript, local-storage

hey i am  trying to make a phonebook where everytime i add someones name and phonenumber it displays it into the front page and then i can remove or edit...
now i have tried to add a remove function so it removes only the one row or name i choose after many tries i noticed in the application(in the inspect where the developers tools) there is only one key and it seems like i am storing all the arrays (values) into it , now what if i want to remove one value only from the key i  am not sure if its possible
maybe i have to make it so i have multiple keys with each key with its own value i am not sure

this is my js code

```
"use strict";

function showOverlay(showButton, showContainer) { // this whole funciton opens up the overlay
  const addButton = document.querySelector("." + showButton);
  addButton.addEventListener("click", function addSomthing() {
    document.querySelector("." + showContainer).style.display = 'block';
  });
} //end of function

showOverlay("addBtn", "formContainer");


function cancelOverlay(cancelButton, showContainer) { //this dynamic funciton helps with closing overlays after we are done with the event
  const removeOverlay = document.querySelector("." + cancelButton);
  removeOverlay.addEventListener("click", function removeSomthing() {
    document.querySelector("." + showContainer).style.display = 'none';
  });
} //end of function
cancelOverlay("cancelOverlay", "formContainer");
//

let phoneArray = [];
window.onload = init;

const submitButton = document.getElementById("submitButton"); 
submitButton.addEventListener("click", function addPerson() {
    const person = {
      name: document.getElementById("name").value,
      phoneNumber: document.getElementById("phone").value
    };
    if (person.name != "" && person.phoneNumber != "") {
      phoneArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("person")) || [];
      phoneArray.push(person);
      localStorage.setItem("person", JSON.stringify(phoneArray));
      phoneArray = localStorage.getItem("person");
      phoneArray = JSON.parse(phoneArray);

      window.location.reload(true);
    } //end if
  } //end addPerson)
);

function createLayout(person) {

  const divv = document.getElementById("outPutContainer");
  let row = document.createElement("ul");
  row.innerHTML = `
<li>${person.name} </li>
<li>${person.phoneNumber} </li>
<button class="insideRemoveBtn"> - </button>
`;
  divv.appendChild(row);
} //end of function


function getPersonArray() {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("person"));
} //end of function

function init() {
  const personArray = getPersonArray();
  for (let i = 0; i < personArray.length; i++) {
    const person = personArray[i];
    createLayout(person);
    const insideRemoveBtn = document.querySelector(".insideRemoveBtn");
    insideRemoveBtn.addEventListener("click", function removeSingleItem() {
      localStorage.removeItem('person');
      location.reload(true);
    });
  }
} //end of function

const removeAllBtn = document.getElementById("removeAllBtn");
removeAllBtn.addEventListener("click", function removeAll() {
  localStorage.clear();
  location.reload(true);
});
```

and this is my html code if needed

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>PhoneBook</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Css/Whole.css">
    <script defer src="JavaScript/PU.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>PhoneBook</h1>


    <div class="childContainer">


        <div class="buttonsContainer">
            <div>
                <input type="search" placeholder="search" class="searchBar"></div>
            <div class="buttonsRightSide"> <button value="submit" id="addBtn" class="addBtn">+</button>
                <button value="submit" id="removeAllBtn" class="removeAllBtn">-</button>
                <button value="submit" id="saveBtn" class="saveBtn">*</button></div>
        </div>



        <div class="formContainer">
            <form class="addForm" id="addForm">

                <h2>Create Contact</h2>
                <label for="name">First name*:</label>
                <input id="name" type="text" pattern="[A-Z][a-zA-Z]{3,7}" required><br>
                <label for="phoneNumber">Phone number*:</label>
                <input id="phone" type="number" pattern="[0][5][0-8][ -]?\d{7}" required><br>
                <label for="Adress">Address:</label>
                <input type="text" id="Address"><br>
                <label for="Email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" id="Email"><br>
                <label for="Description">Description:</label>
                <textarea type="text" id="Description"></textarea><br>
                <div class="sendCancelButtons">
                    <button type="submit" class="submitButton" id="submitButton">Send</button>
                     <button value="submit" class="cancelOverlay">Cancel</button></div>
            </form>
        </div>


        <div id="outPutContainer" class="outPutContainer">


        </div>


    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

any hints and suggestions are welcome and  thanks in advance <3

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood from your question, you are storing all your phonebook data inside `person` key. For deleting any specific "person" from the `localStorage` you can parse the array once again and then remove that "person" from array and save it back to `localStorage`. I'm assuming you want to remove person by it's phone number.

```js
function removeByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber){
   const prevArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("person")) || [];
   const newArray = prevArray.filter(_person => _person.phoneNumber !== phoneNumber)
   localStorage.setItem("person", JSON.stringify(newArray))
}
```

Comment: there is a button that i make with js everytime i add a new person it adds this button near it and it has the class insideRemoveBtn now i am trying to assign everyperson to their button and by clicking the button i remove the person , that is what i am trying to do

Comment: localStorage is quite slow and doesn't scale up very well. If you will have thousands of data consider using IndexedDb instead or SQLite. In this case, you can just get the data from localStorage and loop over "person" to create multiple buttons. Each button can trigger `removeByPhoneNumber` for its phoneNumber